# How to use arry as a loop

Tags: javascript, html

Well, it's a bit hard to explain what I need to do, but:

I have an array of 21 strings, and I have a javascript function that works every 3 seconds which looks like this:

```
function Ready(){
    t=setTimeout("change()",3000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    Ready();
});
```

What I don't know how to do is: how would I change a div element (called "id1") every 3 seconds, replacing its text with a new text from the array, from 1 to 21 and then back to 1 again?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your keyboard?

Comment: what you'll need is a global variable, a foreach loop and I think that's pretty much it

Comment: Chasing death, can you expline abit more please?:) and myabe show me a function. thanks!  , jivings, i have a problem in enligsh. no need to lol on me.

Comment: you have a problem *in* typing Mr. Alon M from **Isreal**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses something called an "anonymous function", that takes the place of "change()" in your question. This is the proper way to use setTimeout.

```
var arrPtr = 0;  // <-- this is the array pointer varialble.
vat txtArr = "a,b,c,d".split(",") //<-- this contains your string array

function Ready() {
   t=setTimeout(function(){
       $('#id1').html(txtArr[arrPtr]); //<-- this puts the value or the arrayat position "arrPtr" into your page
       arrPtr++; // <-- this increments the position to the next element
       if(arrPtr>txtArr.length) {
          arrPtr = 0;  // <--- this resets the position to zero when it gets to the end of the array
       }  
   },3000);
}
```

Comment: I didn't really understood it, can you give me a easyer exmple please?

Comment: I've added some comments. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = ["Hello", "World"];
var changeInterval = null;
var changeIteration = 0;
var change = function(){
   $('#id1').text(str[changeIteration++ % str.length]);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    change();
    changeInterval = setInterval(change,3000);
});
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/feKcm/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myStrings = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"];
    var interval = setInterval(changeValue, 3000);
    var index = 0;

    function changeValue() {
        var idx = (index + myStrings.length) % myStrings.length;
        document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = myStrings[idx];
        index++;
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/huHJx/1/)